# Three.js How to move an object over terrain so the object rotates to match the contours

Tags: three.js

In my example I am moving a tank over a bridge. I can see that there are two approaches to this problem one is to let physics handle the Math and the other is to calculate the height and rotation values for the vehicle manually (this is the approach I would like to take).

So far I have had some success with various different approaches and I will describe them below:

To start with I am using an Axis Aligned Bounding Box (AABB).From here I set an arbitrary height and project down from the 4 corners to find 4 points that intersect with the ground terrain. At these 4 points a calculate an upward vector using the cross product of the x and z axis:

```
// slopePoints[4] are the 4 points that interset the ground from the downward raycast
// vec2, vec6, vec7 make up the x and z axis for the base of the tank 

var xDirSlope = slopePoints[3].clone().sub( slopePoints[0] ).normalize();
var zDirSlope = slopePoints[2].clone().sub( slopePoints[3] ).normalize();

var slopeNormalVector = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors( xDirSlope, zDirSlope );

var xDirObjectBase = vec6.clone().sub( vec7 ).normalize();
var zDirObjectBase = vec2.clone().sub( vec6 ).normalize();

var baseNormalVector  = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors( xDirObjectBase, zDirObjectBase );
```

So now I have two normalized vectors (1) represents the upward vector for the position the tank "should" be in and (2) represents the upward vector for the position the tank "is" in now.

(1) is derived from the rays cast down that hit the terrain
(2) is the base of the AABB bounding box of the tank

My next step is to calculate the angle between the two vectors and the axis required for transformation as follows:

```
var radians = Math.acos( baseNormalVector.dot( slopeNormalVector ) );

var axis = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors( baseNormalVector, slopeNormalVector );
```

So now have calculated the angle in radians and the axis for transformation I should be able to rotate my tank on the required axis using :

```
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis( axis, radians );

object.applyMatrix( matrix );
```

When I apply this logic I can see that the tank rotates to match the contour of the bridge but then it kind of pulls a wheelie and eventually settles correctly on the other side of the bridge.

My observation is that the tank should rotate on its x-axis while it enters the start of the bridge but the rotation should go from a positive delta to a negative delta as it approaches the half way mark but it doesn't it simply continues to rise.

Other approaches have been:

// Using Quaternion Tank behves strangely and doesn't even move onto bridge before goes verticle

```
quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors( baseNormalVector, slopeNormalVector );
matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationFromQuaternion( quaternion );

// By calculating the rotational delta as I move over the bridge

radians = baseNormalVector.angleTo( slopeNormalVector );
object.rotateX( radians )
```

I've tried calculating the rotational delta as I move over the bridge so as I start I have a +angle and as I get over 45deg mark I change to -angle to bring tank back flat as it moves over the centre point of the bridge and then the reverse to bring the tank down. This worked ok althought I'm not happy with the approach and it also causes problems when you change the direction of the tank and the bridge.

Any help guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I have an solution that works although it may not be the best way it is reliable.

1. Create a Vector that represents the objects local x-axis in world units not a vector (1,0,0) this vector must move when the object rotates.
2. Get the forward vector as the cross product of slopeNormalVector an the local x-axis vector
3. Project a point down the foward vector an arbitraty distance.
4. use object.lookAt to point to forward trajectory

See below

```
var xObject   = object.getObjectByName( "xObject" );
var xPosition = new THREE.Vector3();

xPosition.setFromMatrixPosition( xObject.matrixWorld );

var xVector       = new THREE.Vector3().copy( xPosition ).sub( object.position ).normalize();
var forwardVector = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors( xVector, slopeNormalVector ).normalize();
var pointForward  = new THREE.Vector3().copy( forwardVector ).multiplyScalar( 2000 ).add( object.position );
```

I add an invisible object and translateX to the object when loaded to use to calculate my xVector.

This solution works for all directions of the object and terrain.